# How to get access to object via name or in console

Tags: javascript, json, console

I have this object outputting to the console, but I can't seem to find it following the path window.type or window.name. Is there a way to find the object through track.link or attach it to the window somehow.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is a custom event. So something on your page has something.trigger('track.link').

Comment: Wouldn't you just log it with `track.link`, and then access its children with `track.link.name` and such? Depending on how `track` is created, you might need to tie it into a DOM ready handler.

Comment: It looks like the output of `console.log("track.link", someArbitraryObject)`. The "name" has no significance. Show us the call that logs this.

Comment: @obsidianage track.link returns that it isn't defined yet

Comment: No way to know from what is shown what scope is for that object. Do a file search for that term *"track.link"*

Comment: is there possibly a way to get an array of all similar objects? or is it not available to console.

Comment: try this, in one of your js code, add  `$('*').on('track.link', function(e){ console.trace(e); });` To me it is a event handler. This way you can see what is triggering it. But be aware that this will reduce your page's performance until you remove it because it attaches an event listener to all elements.

Comment: @serdar.sanri it is clearly not a jQuery event object

Comment: @serdar.sanri I get a huge array that is about 2689 elements long

Comment: once it is triggered or as soon as you put that in your code? @charlietfl you are right, there is no currentTarget or handleObj.

Comment: nevermind about my comment above, @charlietfl is right. That's not an even obj.

Comment: You're having difficulty **finding** which script the `track` variable is coming from? I created a small script to do that [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/bd76oms0/). As for utilisation of the variable, first check its scope, and then check that it exists at the point you're trying to target it with event delegation.

Comment: @obsidianage thank you will try now